# WebView using NavigateToLocalStreamUri doesn't actually Navigate

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I have a WebView that I am using to load local files from ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder. I made a method to calling Navigate on the WebView

```
public override void BrowserNavigateLocal(string fileName)
{
   Uri uri = browser.BuildLocalStreamUri("page", fileName);
   browser.NavigateToLocalStreamUri(uri, new MyStreamUriResolver());
}
```

My IUriToStreamResolver looks like this

```
public sealed class MyStreamUriResolver : IUriToStreamResolver
{
    public IAsyncOperation<IInputStream> UriToStreamAsync(Uri uri)
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            if (uri == null)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            string path = uri.AbsolutePath;
            return GetContent(path).AsAsyncOperation();
        }
    }

    private async Task<IInputStream> GetContent(string path)
    {
        try
        {

            Uri localUri = new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/HTML" + path);

            //StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(localUri);
            //IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

            StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(localUri).AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
            IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read).AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (true)
            {
                Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader reader = new DataReader(stream);
                await reader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
                string fileContent = reader.ReadString((uint)stream.Size);
                stream.Seek(0);
            }
            return stream;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Path is invalid");
        }
    }
}
```

I've included some debugging code that allows me to check the file contents for everything the WebView is requesting. Everything looks good with the files and no Exceptions are thrown.

My first call to BrowserNavigateLocal() works perfectly, but it won't load my second page. The WebView just stays on it's current page.

The WebView raises the NavigationStarting and ContentLoading events, but NavigationCompleted never gets hit for the second page.

*Edit: I can confirm that the html on my second page is causing the issue. I tried to Navigate to a temporary page and it worked perfectly. I still have no idea how to go about debugging my second page.*

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. My html page was making an ajax request for a local file, using JQuery. In my ajax request, I had set the "async" flag to true. Windows 8.1 apparently doesn't like it when you do that.